# How to send, receive and store references to external Methods

Tags: java, android

In a custom Class I'm trying to execute functions that are given externally via parameters.

It is important for me not to have to store any reference to parent classes or such, only the methods/functions to be called.

I tried sending a Method as a parameter but it isn't working.

```
class A
    // var to store reference to external method
    private Method myMethodReference;  // (says error: never used)

    // the setter to store the reference to the external method
    public void setMethodReference(Method someMethod)
    {
        myMethodReference = someMethod;
    }

    public boolean someFunctionWithinMyClass()
    {
        // call the external method via my reference
        myMethodReference();  // (says error: The method myMethodReference() is undefined)
    }
```

---

Also, when I try to set the reference to the method from the external class, it doesn't work:

```
class B

    public void someFunction() { Log.i("la", "la" };

    instanceOfClassA.setMethodReference(someFunction); // (says error: variable someFunction not found)
```

---

So even passing the reference doesn't work because Eclipse assumes someFunction is a variable that is not in the scope.

I hope this explains it better!

Comment: Practically speaking, you'll need a reference. Even if you pass a Method instance, the first argument of Method.invoke() is the object you want to invoke the method on.

Comment: @reassembler could you give me an example? How can I use a reference?

Comment: To be clear. I don't believe it's possible to do what you want. "Call a method on an object without having a reference to that object." You will need to store a reference to that object somewhere.

Comment: Looking at your class B example I see the problem. Java doesn't have [Closures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_science)). The Java pattern most used to solve this problem is anonymous inner classes. Android makes heavy use of this.

Answer (score 0):

```
private Method  onClick;
```

This **above** line will generate an error....

You should create or declare a method this way...

```
public onClick(){


}
```

**or**

`public abstract onClick();`

Now.... you have called `onClick()` **without implementing** `onClick()`, **that led to the error.**

Comment: Thanks for the input but I know how to declare methods... And abstract variables can only be defined by an abstract class, which is not the case, I'm working with Views and Activities. I wonder if you understood my question properly. I will edit it to make more clear. Thanks again!